# What are my alternatives to manage Python packages for clients?

Tags: python, distribution, package

So the setup is a slew of proprietary server/client Python applications running on one Linux box (the server) and a set of Windows 7 workstations (the clients). Everything is running smoothly until any of the proprietary Python packages needs updating.

For now I am using `distutils` eggs which are very easily updated with `easy_install`, but it is still a manual process which quickly becomes tedious as the number of applications and client workstations grow.

The ideal setup IMHO is to have the Python packages on the server so when a client application is launched on a workstation the client application can check to see whether its current Python packages are up-to-date. If not, the client application should download the newer Python package from the server, install it, and then launch as per normal.

Does this sounds familiar to anyone? I have tried to find alternatives myself, but as far as I can see there is no Python module offering this functionality. Does anyone have any home made solutions for this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes! [`pip2pi`](https://github.com/wolever/pip2pi) is should be exactly what you are looking for.

From the docs:

> pip2pi builds a PyPI-compatible package repository from pip requirements

`pip2pi` allows you to create your own PyPI index by using two simple commands:

1. To mirror a package and all of its requirements, use `pip2tgz`:

   ```
   $ cd /tmp/; mkdir package/
   $ pip2tgz packages/ httpie==0.2
   ...
   $ ls packages/
   Pygments-1.5.tar.gz
   httpie-0.2.0.tar.gz
   requests-0.14.0.tar.gz
   ```
2. To build a package index from the previous directory:

   ```
   $ ls packages/
   bar-0.8.tar.gz
   baz-0.3.tar.gz
   foo-1.2.tar.gz
   $ dir2pi packages/
   $ find packages/
   /httpie-0.2.0.tar.gz
   /Pygments-1.5.tar.gz
   /requests-0.14.0.tar.gz
   /simple
   /simple/httpie
   /simple/httpie/httpie-0.2.0.tar.gz
   /simple/Pygments
   /simple/Pygments/Pygments-1.5.tar.gz
   /simple/requests
   /simple/requests/requests-0.14.0.tar.gz
   ```
3. To install from the index you built in step 2., you can simply use:

   ```
   pip install --index-url=file:///tmp/packages/simple/ httpie==0.2
   ```

You can also mirror your own index to a *remote host* with `pip2pi`.

Comment: To add the OP wants to have the binary auto update it self from what it looks like. To use the above you could make the application call the above then after updating run. I couldn't find something in a Python lib to do that, besides hot loading code on the fly but that can get messy.

Comment: @sean oh thanks for the addition :) it's really late for me today but hopefully I will take another look at the question tomorrow.